# How to use BaseGameActivity.getApiClient() in multiple activities?

Tags: android, android-activity, google-play-services, google-play-games

In my game app I would like the user to sign in to Google Play Services during the starting activity so I had it subclass `BaseGameActivity`. Then a separate activity is started for the game, at the end of which I want to update a leaderboard using Google Play Services, which requires calling `BaseGameActivity.getApiClient()`.

How should I use Google Play services from a different activity than the one that subclasses `BaseGameActivity`?

Two options I thought of were: pass a reference to the starting activity, or use a handler and send a message to the starting activity. But I don't know which would method would be better to use (or if a third way is better) and it seems like this might be a fairly common situation.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use `GameHelper` with multiple activities it is best to implement it without using `BaseGameActivity` and then pass your `GameHelper` instance between activities (or keep a static instance somewhere).

You can find instructions for using `GameHelper` directly [on this page](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init) (see the **Using GameHelper without BaseGameActivity** heading).

Just make sure that you place the required `GameHelper` calls (especially `onActivityResult`) in all of your activities that make use of it. As for sign-on/sign-out you will need to determine for yourself in which activity(s) to place those, depending on the flow of your app.

Comment: Is there any reason to not subclass both activities from `BaseGameActivity` and in the one that I don't want to automatically sign-on put `getGameHelper().setMaxAutoSignInAttempts(0);`?

Comment: You could do that but the `onCreate()` of the `BaseGameActivity` would recreate the `mHelper` for each activity and the state of the new object would not necessarily be correct - i.e. the new object's internal states might not reflect whether you are already signed-on (or vice-versa). I'm sure there is a way to get it to sync up properly, but it seems like alot of effort as opposed to just using the `GameHelper` independently.

Comment: The issue with using `GameHelper` independently is AFAIK there is no good way to pass unserializable/parcelable objects (such as `GameHelper`) between activities and making it static seems like a bad idea as `GameHelper` holds a reference to the activity that created it.

Comment: You are absolutely correct, I hadn't even considered that it keeps the original activity as a reference. You could replace those values, but that seems like a very bad way to go about it. I suppose they designed the `BaseGameUtils` with single activity applications in mind (which most games would be anyways). It seems that implementing it in each activity is the only **proper** way to do it, but it will need to disconnect/reconnect for each activity - which should not be a problem as long as it doesn't happen too frequently.

Comment: It appears that the best practice is to have one activity that has `GameHelper` tied to it and use fragments if at all possible.

Comment: I just saw [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24235549/1326821) answer, which seems to be good way for using Google Play services with multiple activities.