# Persist Google Play Services login between activities

Tags: android, android-activity, google-play-services, google-play-games

I thought this would be straightforward, but I've been going in circles trying to figure out how to keep a user logged in between `Activities`.

I have a "Main" and a "Details" `Activity`.  A user logs into `Google Play Services` in the "Main" `Activity` and I want to submit achievements and leaderboard data in the "Details" `Activity`.

I'm inheriting from `BaseGameActivity` in both `Activities` and using:

```
 mGoogleApiClient = getApiClient();
```

in "Details", however when I call `isConnected` it always returns `false`.

I even tried copying all the login/callback code from the "Main" `Activity` over, but it's still doesn't detect the user is logged in.

This post suggests not using `BaseGameActivity` and pass `GameHelper` using a `singleton`:

[How to use BaseGameActivity.getApiClient() in multiple activities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24147835/how-to-use-basegameactivity-getapiclient-in-multiple-activities)

Not sure what the correct approach is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most simple way to do this is to have both activities create a separate instance of the api client. The state of the connection is shared between them internally, so you don't need worry about how to pass around the client and handle callbacks that may happen when an activity is not active, and the player will only log in on your main activity.

Extending your activity from BaseGameActivity really is not needed any longer (for an entertaining explanation watch: [Death of BasegameActivity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1oSoaFLuTwM). What you do need to do is implement the two interfaces that handle initializing the GoogleAPIClient:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
        }
```

To implement these, refer to the samples and the doc: https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init

Comment: That video is hilarious. Damn, that's how I implemented the API originally the changed it to use BaseGameActivity.  Guess I'll just revert.  Thanks.