# Google leaderboard submitscore error:GoogleApiClient must be connected

Tags: android, google-play-games

Getting problem in saving score in leaderboard.

In my case first in login screen is which user login using google.
Second screen is game activity and after finishing game i want score to be save in leaderboard.

I am using below code for GoogleApiClient initialization :-

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)

        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
        .build();
setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
```

For saving game score :-

```
 Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(mGoogleApiClient, getResources().getString(R.string.leaderboard_id), millis);
```

But it is saying:- GoogleApiClient must be connected.

But when a add sign in api to google client like below it is saying you can not use Games.Api with Sign_in_api.

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this , this )
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
            .build();
```

Basically my question is how can i connect GoogleApiClient in my secound activity so that i can use Games.Leaderboards.submitScore to save game score.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be using `BaseGameActivity`, extending your activity is no longer needed. Instead, use `BaseGameUtils` library to resolve connection errors and display dialogs.

Try initializing [GoogleApiClient](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient) by implementing the `GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks` and `GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener` interfaces. See this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init) for more information.

```
import com.google.android.gms.*;
import com.google.example.games.basegameutils.BaseGameUtils;

public class MyGameActivity extends Activity implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
```

For additional insights, you may want to check the following :

- [YouTube video: Game On! - The Death of Base Game Activity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1oSoaFLuTwM)
- [Persist Google Play Services login between activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32339184/persist-google-play-services-login-between-activities)
- [Android: Google play games services connection error ( java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient must be connected.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24474986/android-google-play-games-services-connection-error-java-lang-illegalstateexc/24475540#24475540)