# Android: Get username in Google Play Games

Tags: android, google-play-games

I'm trying to develop a game where the user after `sign in` in `Play Games` is forwarded to another `Activity`. But on this second `Activity` I don't know how to get his `username`. Do I have to `Sign in` again (this time on the second `Activity`) to obtain it?

I tried with

```
GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN).toString();
```

but it returns something like `com.google.candroid.gms.auth.api.signin@` and I what I want is his username in `Play games`, not this.

I was reading this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32339184/persist-google-play-services-login-between-activities?fbclid=IwAR1bOWKZbQP8AAZQxo2L7W8EQMZ9He5gzsjY3zM1vNhRzx26iCzT_l-HP-I) but here I've got to create a `new GoogleApiClient` again to get the it.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount` method to request profile information for the currently signed in user.

```
GoogleSignInAccount acct = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(getActivity());
if (acct != null) {
  String personName = acct.getDisplayName();
  String personGivenName = acct.getGivenName();
  String personFamilyName = acct.getFamilyName();
  String personEmail = acct.getEmail();
  String personId = acct.getId();
  Uri personPhoto = acct.getPhotoUrl();
}
```

To find out more, go to the official documentation: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/people